# why can't i add a list to textBrowser in qt designer?

Tags: python

i'm a newbie and trying my first app. trying to do a combination kind of calculator for displaying different combinations of 2 user inputted food items (a and b) throughout 6 food groups. while trying to get it together, i ran into an issue. i'm using qt designer and python.

here is my partial code that i'm having issues with:

```
def addItem(self):
    a = self.lineEdit.text()
    b = self.lineEdit2.text()
    value = [a, b]
    self.lineEdit.clear()
    self.lineEdit2.clear()
    self.textBrowser.append(value)
```

when pressing my addBtn from two separate lineEdit boxes, it's supposed to put the two in a list set in a textBrowser. i'm hoping to get the browser to look like this:

```
[item1, item3]
[item5, item6]
[item4, item7]
[item2, item9]
[item11, item 8]
item10, item12]
```

Instead i'm getting:
TypeError: append(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'

I've searched and found similar situations, but none dealing with lists. Please help if you can. It'd be greatly appreciated.

*please note, the following code worked prior attempting to make it a list.

```
def addItem(self):
    value = self.lineEdit.text()
    self.lineEdit.clear()
    self.textBrowser.append(value)
```

this code works, but displays in the browser like this:

```
   item1
   item2
   item3
   item4
   item5
   item6
   item7
   item8
   item9
   item10
   item11
   item12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text browser requires that the value set or appended to it be strings. You need to construct the string you need.  Here are some options:

```
value_str = str([a, b])      # type casting, might work for small lists
value_str = '[' + a + ',' + b + ']' # string concatenation
value_str = '[{}, {}]'.format(a, b)    # one of python's 3 string interpolation methods
value_str = f'[{a},{b}]'     # f-string, python 3.6+
```

See here for more tips on str.format: https://pyformat.info/, though you should totally take advantage of f-strings for personal projects if possible.

Have fun building your app!

Comment: thank you so much. you are awesome! worked perfectly. i have both 3.6 and 3.5 but i'm not certain if i'm having to use 3.5, so i used the third option. thanks again! you wouldn't happen to have any ideas about the possible combinations would you?? had to ask. you seem to know what you're doing. lol. thanks again.

Comment: from itertools import product. Then for a, b in product(food_group1, food_group2):  print(a, b).

Comment: It's called the "Cartesian product" apparently. Like the mathematical concept of combinations. Itertools has lots of fun stuff like that. Just know you have to use them with either a for loop or something that takes an iterable because functions like product return generators, which are like a lazy sequence that saves memory. For small stuff or debugging though it can help to do list(product(sequence1, sequence2)) to see all the results in a list.

Comment: i don't know if i explained it correctly. but first let me thank you again. i'll try again, if i may. How do i display the combinations of one item from each food group? and Would I be correct in assuming that the total number of combinations is 64? This is how i got that number: 2 ^ 6 = 64 combinations
i am about to make a question for this. would like to give you another check if possible. @flutefreak7

Comment: i just saw your second comment. that seems so simple and awesome at the same time. i'm about to try it out. i'm worried about repeats tho. but if i wanted to call it from a button to display in another textBrowser, how would i arrange that? @flutefreak7

Comment: Product will return unique pairs if all the items in the 2 lists are different. If you want to remove duplicates at some point you can use set() for that, though sets are unordered, so you might have to re-sort if you care about order. list(set(stuff)) will remove duplicates. You can also find common items between sequences, etc, by doing set math (like intersection, union, etc), which you can research. Time to go play around until you have your next question to submit :). You can also get feedback on Reddit r/learnpython for more conversational discussion.

Comment: i just made a post in r/learnpython could you take a look at it for me? posted under pythonnewb9 with question as: How do I display combinations from a grouped set, that will be called from an addBtn that will be displayed in a textBrowser?